# Include a button in the Grid

Tags: javascript, gridview, asp.net-core-mvc, syncfusion

I'm trying to include button details which allows to go to page detail

```
 $("#Grid").ejGrid({
                dataSource: ej.DataManager({
                 ...
columns: [
{ headerText: 'Detail', commands: ['type:"detail", buttonOptions:{text: "details", click:"OnClick"}} ],},
         ],
```

And then I defined my function:

```
   function OnClick(id){
 var url = '@Url.Action("Detail","ServicesOrder", new {id="__id__"})';
window.location.href=url.replace('__id__',id);
}
```

my controller ServicesOrder

```
 public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {ServicesOrder ServicesOrder = _context.ServicesOrder.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ServicesOrderId.Equals(id));

        if (ServicesOrder == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(ServicesOrder);
    }
```

the mistake I get

This site page is not found at:

**https: // localhost: 44337 / ServicesOrder/Detail/[object% 20Object]**

I have followed to the letter your code, but is not working (see image).
[image: Error 2]

Comment: so you are looking for the code for href? Any reason why you don't move to EJ2? Much easier to work with imo. Especially for tag helpers. Or how to use that in the view?

Comment: first of all, I want to thank you for your answer. about the view, I use `<div id="Grid"></div> `.  and then in my script `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function ()...  $("#Grid").ejGrid({... `

Answer (score 0):

normally I would do this in a template with Syncfusion controls just works better and the tag-helpers just work.

```
//OPTION 1
//your original source
 $("#Grid").ejGrid({
                dataSource: ej.DataManager({
   columns: [
           { headerText: 'Detail' template: "<a href='/ServicesOrder/Details/{{:OrderId}}'>Finiched</a>"},
           { headerText: 'Order #', field: 'OrderId'}]
});
```

```
//OPTION 2
//your original source + tweak

 $("#Grid").ejGrid({
                dataSource: ej.DataManager({
   columns: [
           { headerText: 'Detail', template: true, templateId: "#detailsbutton"}]
});



<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="detailsbutton">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Details", "ServicesOrder", new {id = {{:OrderId}})>Details</a>
</script>
```

As long as the `OrderId` exists in the query for the grid it will find that in the template and populate accordingly. Keep in mind Syncfusion uses JSX extensively under the covers (at least this version which is EJs1, EJs2 is a complete rewrite using pure Javascript).  I

I really have to emphasize that using just `javascript` with `asp.net core mvc` works but adding in clean tag-helpers like:

```
<ejs-grid id="OrderGrid" dataSource=@ViewBag.somedata >
    <e-datamanager></e-datamanager>
 <e-grid-columns>
    <e-grid-column field="Id" type="number"></e-grid-column>
 </e-grid-columns>
</ejs-grid>
```

So much easier to deal with!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, another error that persists (answer from below). About Ejs2, you are absolutely right, I intend to do that because i have just discovered.